# Function not Running inside an "if" statement Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write an escape room game in Python.
When I run the code with pycharm the process ends with "process finished with exit code 0."

Is there something wrong in the defining of the functions?
Here is my code (its a bit lengthy):

```
choice = None

def main_choice():

    print("1. Examine door")

    print("2. Examine painting")

    print("3. Examine desk")

    print("4. Examine bookshelf")

    choice == input("Make your choice: ")


def door():

    print("1. Try to open door")

    print("2. Take a closer look")

    print("3. Go back to where you were.")

    door_choice = input("What now? ")

    if door_choice == "1":

        print("The door is too heavy to open with your bare hands.")

        door()

    if door_choice == "2":

        print("There is a red light above the door, but it seems to have no purpose.")

        print("You notice a 9 key keypad next to the door. It looks like it will accept a 3 digit code.")

        keypad_code = input("Would you like to enter a code?").lower

        if keypad_code == " yes":

             guess = input("ENTER CODE: ")

             if guess == complete_key:

             print("The light turns green and you hear the sound of a mechanical lock unlocking. The door opens.")

             print("YOU WIN!!!")

        if guess != complete_key:

             print("Wrong code.")

             main_choice()

    if door_choice == "3":

        main_choice()

    else:

        print("You didn't answer")


main_choice()

if choice == "1":

    print("You walk to the door")

    door()
```

I think that it might be the last "if" statement, but I'm not positive.

Comment: basically do you want to keep running program without exit?

Comment: A quick way to debug this would be to place a debug print after you call `main_choice()` to ensure you have assigned `choice` to something first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `choice == input("Make your choice: ")` to `choice = input("Make your choice: ")` in your `main_choice` function:

```
def main_choice():

    print("1. Examine door")

    print("2. Examine painting")

    print("3. Examine desk")

    print("4. Examine bookshelf")

    choice = input("Make your choice: ")
```

Otherwise the `choice` variable will still be `None` and `if choice == "1":` will always be False.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
choice = input("Make you choice: ")
```

rather than:

```
choice == input("Make you choice: ")
```

Double equals signs return a boolean rather than changing a value.